# The average of a random varible with pdf in the form of a parametric integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, asymptotics

The pdf of a random variable $T$  in the interval $(0,1)$ in a certain problem I am trying to solve is given by :
$$ g(t)= c\int_{0}^{1-t} t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1} d u $$ where c is some constant.We know the average $E(T)$ is given by :

$$E(T)=\int_0^1t g(t) dt=\int_0^1 t\left[c\int_{0}^{1-t} t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1} d u \right] dt.$$
For m=2 ,$g(t)$ can be evaluated exactly and hence $E(T)$ also.However,for general $m$ it is not immediately clear  to me how $E(T)$ can be evaluated analytically or even numerically . As a first attempt  I tried to evaluate this integral  by parts by taking $g(t)$ as the first function and calculating $g'(t)$ .It however did not help.I want to know if there is some way of calculating the above integral for the expectation of T,for general values of  positive integer values of  $m$ and $n$ or even for the asymptotic case of $m$ and $n$.I would highly appreciate if somebody could help me with this integral.$$'$$
**PS:** To be specific ,$g(t)$ is the pdf of  range of the distances from origin of n *iid* points in the n-dimensional ball and $c=m^2n(n-1).$For $m=2,3 $, it can be seen the expectation approaches 1 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Is this a question about the computing software *Mathematica*? If not, you probably want to ask this question on [math.se] or Cross Validated Stack Exchange.

Comment: _Mathematica_ can't do this integral for general n,m ,  nor can it do it with `Rubi`. But if you provide n,m values it can handle it: ```g = With[{m = 2, n = 2}, 
   c Integrate[
     t^(m - 1) ((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2) (u + t)^(m - 1), {u, 0, 
      1 - t}]
   ];
Integrate[t g, {t, 0, 1}]```

Comment: @March ..yes it is about Mathematica

Comment: Does this answer your question:
`r[m_?IntegerQ, n_?IntegerQ] := 
 With[{gt = 
    c Integrate[
      t^(m - 1) ((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2) (u + t)^(m - 1), {u, 0, 
       1 - t}]},
  Integrate[t gt, {t, 0, 1}]
  ] `   `r[4, 3]`  (oops, I just saw that I duplicated @flinty's answer (sorry)